# How can I get information about the trees in a Random Forest in sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I would like to learn more about the Random Forest Regressors I am building with sklearn. For example, which depth do the trees have on average if I do not regularise?

The reason for this is that I need to regularise the model and want to get a feeling for what the model looks like at the moment. Also, if I set e.g. `max_leaf_nodes` will it still be necessary to also restrict `max_depth` or will this "problem" sort of solve itself because the tree cannot be grown too deep it `max_leaf_nodes` is set. Does this make sense or am I thinking in the wrong direction? I could not find anything in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know the average maximum depth of the trees constituting your Random Forest model, you have to access each tree singularly and inquiry for its maximum depth, and then compute a statistic out of the results you obtain.

Let's first make a reproducible example of a Random Forest classifier model (taken from [Scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html))

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=4,
                           n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                           random_state=0, shuffle=False)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                             random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Now we can iterate over its `estimators_` attribute containing each decision tree. For each decision tree, we inquiry the attribute `tree_.max_depth`, store away the response and take an average after completing our iteration:

```
max_depth = list()
for tree in clf.estimators_:
    max_depth.append(tree.tree_.max_depth)

print("avg max depth %0.1f" % (sum(max_depth) / len(max_depth)))
```

This will provide you an idea of the average maximum depth of each tree composing your Random Forest model (it works exactly the same also for a regressor model, as you have asked about).

Anyway, as a suggestion, if you want to regularize your model, you have better test parameter hypothesis under a [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) and [grid/random search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) paradigm. In such a context you actually don't need to question yourself how hyperparameters interact with each other, you just test different combinations and you get the best combination based on cross validation score.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I will be using grid search for hyperparameter tuning but I wanted to get a feeling for the problem and the method.

Comment: Using the code I provided you can get the statistics you need about the average maximum depth of the trees in your Random Forest based on your choice of the hyperparameters max_leaf_nodes and  max_depth.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Luca Massaron's answer:

I found https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py which can be applied to each tree in the forest using

```
for tree in clf.estimators_:
```

The number of leaf nodes can be calculated like this:

```
n_leaves = np.zeros(n_trees, dtype=int)
for i in range(n_trees):
    n_nodes = clf.estimators_[i].tree_.node_count
    # use left or right children as you want 
    children_left = clf.estimators_[i].tree_.children_left
    for x in range(n_nodes):
        if children_left[x] == -1:
            n_leaves[i] += 1
```